# Is this topology related problem wrong?

Tags: general-topology

One of my friend sent me this question. I think it is a wrong question

Why?

When we define topology on $X$, we talk about set of all subsets of $X$. Here $(1,2018]$ is not even a subset of $X$, so we can not say anything about whether it is open or closed in $X$.

[image]

Comment: Yes, $2018$ is not in $X$.  So $\#2$ is vacuously true and $\#1$ is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1$ and $2$ are indeed meaningless because $(1,2018]$ is not even a subset of $X$.

$3$ is not true because $1$ is not an interior point of it.

$4$ is also meaningless: $0 \notin X$ so it is not even a candidate to be a limit point of any subset of $X$. Its negation is really voidly true:

$0$ is a limit point of $A$ iff for all open sets of $X$, **if** $0 \in O$ then $O \cap A\setminus\{x\} \neq \emptyset$. But we never have $0 \in O$ so the implication is always true and so the statement on the right hand side is true and $0$ is a limit point of $A$ (whatever $A$ is). So we could defend the negation of 4 to be true, so likewise that 4 is false.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification for (4) point. I did not have any solid reasoning except the fact that $0$ does not belong to $X$. I think it is example of a non complete metric space as $1/n$ is a cauchy sequence but limit does not lie in the space. Am I right?

Comment: @MathamanTopologius Sure, it's a non-complete metric space.